# Dynamic initialization of a dictionary value to zero in Python

Tags: python, counter

I am assigning the dictionary keys on the fly after detecting what language a predicted string belongs to and I was wondering how to initialize it to zero.

```
from textblob import TextBlob


correct = {}     

    for i in max_dist_indices:          
...
        correct[TextBlob(predicted_labels[j]).detect_language()] += 1*(predicted_labels[i] == labels[i])
```

Where d`etect.language()` returns a string according to the language in the predicted labels, '*en*' for English, which serves as the key.
Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: you can use `dict.get(key,default_value)` to set the default value as zero or `setdefault(key,0)`

Comment: I'd recommend [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or [`defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the `collections` module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dict.get` method:

```
language = TextBlob(predicted_labels[j]).detect_language()
correct[language] = correct.get(language, 0) + (predicted_labels[i] == labels[i])
```

or you can initialize `correct` as `defaultdict(int)` instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict
correct = defaultdict(int)
correct[language] += predicted_labels[i] == labels[i]
```

Comment: Another option is to use `defaultdict` from the `collections` module, as `defaultdict(int)` creates an entry of value `0` when a key is not present.

Comment: @DillonDavis Sure, updated my answer with it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With dictionaries, you have key-value pairs. When you say you want to initialise a key to 0, I think you mean you want to initialise its value to 0.

Assuming that `1*(predicted_labels[i]` is not equal to `labels[i])` and will therefore return 0,  the following should give what you want:

`correct[TextBlob(predicted_labels[j]).detect_language()] = 1*(predicted_labels[i] == labels[i])`